# API 33 Android 13 non-media files not found

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-13

I am developing an app for API 33, Android 13, and non-media files are not found. According to Google, you do not need permissions to find non-media files, but these are not found, even with permissions set. Until Android 12, I got the option for "Allow management of all Files", but in Android 13, this is not possible.

When I recursively scan .bin and .png files, in Android 12 and 13, it finds both in 12, but only finds .png in 13. I do see the .bin file with the Files application in 13.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

These won't work, any suggestions how to find the .bin file?
I put the files on

```
/storage/
/sdcard/
```

Comment: You cannot put files on /storage and /sdcard for Android 11+ devices to begin with.

Comment: Well, that's where you're wrong and I just did it.

Comment: You did not understand my comment. Please show full paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to request all files permissions and then the .bin file was found on the sdcard. Tested on API 29, 31, 33.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MainActivity

```
private void checkForExternalPermission() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
      PermissionActivity.requestStoragePermission(this, true);
    }
  } else {
    PermissionActivity.requestAllFilesAccess(this);
  }
}
```

PermissionActivity

For storage permission < Android 13

```
startActivity(
  new Intent(
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
    Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))));
```

PermissionActivity

For all files permissions Android 13

```
Intent intent =
  new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
  .setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```